# standard way to guaranty messaging-gateway orderly boot-up and shutdown

Tags: spring-integration

In spring-boot is there's a "best-practice" way to guaranty the orderly boot-up and orderly shutdown of a messaging-gateway ?

By "orderly", I mean here, to guaranty that no message will be send too early or too late through that gateway during the spring application life-cycle (potentially leading to exceptions like "dispatcher doesn't exist").
My current idea is to use a "ContextRefreshedEvent" listener (during start-up) and an OrderlyShutdownCapable implementation in the component controlling my messaging-gateway...is that the right approach ?

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

We recommend to implement such a logic in the `SmartLifecycle`. So, you start send messages in the `start()` implementation and stop in the `stop()` respectively.